# Configuring functionResponseType in typescript serverless template

Tags: typescript, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I am trying to configure `functionResponseType` in a TypeScript Serverless framework template (in order to make use of partial batch responses).

This is my event declaration for the function in question:

```
    events: [
        {
            sqs: {
                arn: {
                    'Fn::GetAtt': [
                        'TheQueue',
                        'Arn'
                    ]
                },
                batchSize: 40,
                maximumBatchingWindow: 10,
                functionResponseType: "ReportBatchItemFailures",
            },
        },
    ],
```

This is what the sqs block looks like in the type declaration file:

```
{
    sqs:
        | AwsArnString
        | {
            arn: AwsArn;
            batchSize?: number;
            enabled?: boolean;
            maximumBatchingWindow?: number;
            functionResponseType?: "ReportBatchItemFailures";
            filterPatterns?: FilterPatterns;
          };
}
```

(The source is here: https://github.com/serverless/typescript/blob/master/index.d.ts#L534-L543)

When I include the `functionResponseType` property, the template does not compile, with the following error:

> Types of property 'functionResponseType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ReportBatchItemFailures"'.ts(2322)

If I remove the `functionResponseType` property the template compiles fine and the function deploys as expected (but then without the partial SQS response functionality).

I am no TypeScript guru, so I am sort of stuck here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code snippet is not representative enough but from the error message you get, the problem comes from a strict type (literal `ReportBatchItemFailures"`) used with a `string` type which is less strict. So to fix this, either type `functionResponseType` as `string` or provide the stricter type when calling it.

Comment: @3Dos thank you for the comment. I have added the type declaration (from serverless framework) for the sqs block. As I interpret it, the property `functionResponseType` is a string that can either be `null`, missing or the exact string `"ReportBatchItemFailures"`. If I assign `null` or remove the property it works. If I assign the string `"ReportBatchItemFailures"` it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"ReportBatchItemFailures" as const` to make it type safe